# JQuery value of input text not working as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, return-value

I'm using javascript/jquery to calculate some simple formulas. I'm doing this by creating objects and then using the value of an HTML input element as the parameters needed to execute and return the answer.

Here's the javascript (the HTML and CSS is provided in the jsfiddle link at the end of this question):

```
var recP = $("#recP");
var recA = $("#recA");
var ansr = $("#ansr");
var l = $("#l").val();
var w = $("#w").val();

//rectangle
function Rectangle(length,width) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;

    this.calcPerim = function() {
        return (this.length * 2) + (this.width * 2);
    };
    this.calcArea = function() {
        return this.length * this.width;
    };
};

var rectangle = new Rectangle(l,w); // l and w are defined in the above variables
var recPerim = rectangle.calcPerim(l,w);
var recArea = rectangle.calcArea(l,w);

recP.click(function() {
    ansr.append("The perimeter is " + recPerim);    
});

recA.click(function() {
    ansr.append("The area is " + recArea);  
});
```

If I set the value of the input elements, I get the expected result. Example:

```
<input type="text" id="l" value="3" />
<input type="text" id="w" value="4" />
```

will return 12 for the area and 14 for the perimeter, but when the value is changed in the input box, it still returns the same values. It's really frustrating and I can't figure out what's wrong. I've even tried not setting a value, but that just returns 0.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy8zj/) with all the HTML, CSS, and JS. If you change the values, the result is still the same. I'm new to javascript so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get values from inputs and calculate *in* click handlers. It'll be a little copy-pasty but

```
recP.click(function() {
    var l = $("#l").val();
    var w = $("#w").val();
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(l,w);
    var recPerim = rectangle.calcPerim(l,w);
    ansr.append("The perimeter is " + recPerim);    
});

recA.click(function() {
    var l = $("#l").val();
    var w = $("#w").val();
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(l,w);
    var recArea = rectangle.calcArea(l,w);
    ansr.append("The area is " + recArea);  
});
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm5XM/)

Comment: that works and it is actually better because now I dont have to define new variables for lengths and withs of other shapes. But what is the reason why it only works when everything is local and not global?

Comment: it gets values only once on first script run

Answer (score 2):

the reason the value isn't changing when you change the values in the input fields is because recPerim and recArea are just holding the values returned by the functions in your rectangle object:

```
recP.click(function() {
    ansr.append("The perimeter is " + recPerim);    
});

recA.click(function() {
    ansr.append("The area is " + recArea);  
});
```

So they are always going to be 14 and 12, because these are the values you passed to your rectangle object when you first created it:

```
var l = $("#l").val();
var w = $("#w").val();
```

If you want the values to change with every click, you need to call .val() again to fetch the content that is now in the input fields. So one solution using your rectangle class would be to create a new rectangle each time, passing in the values that are in currently the input field:

```
recP.click(function() {
var l = $("#l").val();
var w = $("#w").val(); 
var rectangle = new Rectangle(l,w);
var recPerim = rectangle.calcPerim(l,w);
    ansr.append("The perimeter is " + recPerim);    
});

recA.click(function() {
var l = $("#l").val();
var w = $("#w").val(); 
var rectangle = new Rectangle(l,w);
var recArea = rectangle.calcArea(l,w);
    ansr.append("The area is " + recArea);  
});
```

like so. (You can also use ansr.html('The area is...') instead - .html() will explicitly set inner html inside the #ansr div (instead of appending) so if you click on the buttons multiple times, you won't get a long string of answers.)

Comment: thanks for adding in that last part of changing .append to .html, I was just wondering how I could do that!